# Accessing web app from personal project [C#]

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

I would like to know how can I access some web application from my personal project in C#?

To be specific, I would like to access this website https://dictation.io/

In my console app in VS record speech from my mic then pass it to that web app and then returns in my app result as e.g. string. 
If someone could give an advice, it would be really fine (not looking for exact code)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, accessing external resources (such as Dictation.io) would require an API. As they don't offer one, there's no (legal) way to use *their* speech-to-text.

Instead, you can build your own using Microsoft's own libraries and APIs. An example, and probably your best bet, would be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Yeah i tried that before but accuracy of recognition is pretty bad. I need it for my thesis so recognition should be spontaneous and it should recognize speech from the field. 
Any other ideas what to use? Or how could I improve recognition using system.speech?

Comment: Without developing your own or having a license to use someone elses, the options are few and far between